# How to queue the hidden navigation anchors and the hidden search form when burger icon is clicked in small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu consists of (floated left logo , navigation anchors - 
floated right search form) on large and medium screens and (floated left logo , 
floated right burger icon) on small and extra small screens

```
<div class="navbar">
   <a  href="#"> <img class="navbar-brand" 
    src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50"/> </a>
  <div class="search-form">
     <form>
        <input type="text" class="search-input">
        <button type="submit" class="search-button"><img src=""/></button>
     </form>
  </div> 
  <div class="navigators">
     <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resourses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{float:left}
.search-form{float:right}
.tabs{list-style:none;display:inline-block;}
.tabs li{float:left;}
```

Then I have a burger icon that is hidden on large and medium screens :

```
<label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></input>
```

CSS on medium and large screens :

```
.tog,#toggle {display:none}
```

On small and extra small screens when the  clicked :

```
 #toggle:checked  + .search-form  {display:inline}
 #toggle:checked  ~ .navigators {display:inline}
```

But they appear on the navigation menu on a separated places , I want them to be show in a vertical list beneth the burger icon when it's clicked , Is that's possible or I will need to duplicate  the anchors and the search form and style them to be a vertical list ?

**The website is responsive so I don't need a solution that won't be responsive**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like Bootstrap that accomplishes this already through their [Navbar component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar)

You're probably using the input so that you can toggle the `checked` psuedo class, but there is a more elegant solution using CSS and JavaScript for its intended purposes rather than a hacky fix. If you want to implement it yourself there is a more elegant solution to simplify your large and medium screens. You don't want to use `label` and `input` (also `<input/>` is a self closing tag) for a click unless you're submitting something in a `form` so that you can be syntactically correct for SEO and scalability. You can see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danbuda/pen/gwPwjy) as a good example of using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to come up with a good solution.

A [blog post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-an-absolute-basic-mobile-css-responsive-navigation-menu) from Team Treehouse has a great example of using a pure CSS responsive menu.